How to remove a directory from windows 11 %PATH% variable?
I want to remove "C:\Users\M\miniconda3\condabin" from my system %PATH% in windows 11.
It doesn't appear in GUI window for editing environmental variables.
But when I use echo %PATH, it appears!

But when I use echo %PATH in which terminal are you executon this command?
